# How to know when a JQuery function is fired?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I created two JQuery plugins: `_formValidator.validate()` and `refreshTime`
in plugin `_formValidator.validate()`. I have a function for error message generation which name is `buildError`,
and I call these two plugins in a button click.

I want know if the `buildError` function in plugin `_formValidator.validate()` is fired , plugin `refreshTime` doesn't fire.

My code is :

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $("#submitchangepassword").click(function () {
         _formValidator.validate();
         refreshTime({ target: this });
     });
 });
```

`buildError` function code:

```
function buildError( config ) {
    var error = $('<div name="formError" id="formError' + config.controlToValidate.replace('#', '') + '" class="form-error-holder"><div class="form-error-icon"></div><div class="form-error"><span class="form-error">' + config.errormessage + '</span></div><div class="clear"></div></div>');
    error.hide();
    error.insertAfter( config.insertAfterControl );
    error.show('fast');
}
```

Comment: Add `console.log` statements in your functions to see if they are executed.

Comment: thank's , i want checked this is fired, for example:
if(is fired){ refreshTime({ target: this })}

Comment: Just set a flag/value in a global variable when the relevant event fires. One flag per event will let you do whatever you want.

Comment: @HiTechMagic thank's for your answer, but it's possible show me in code?

Comment: Example added... Let me know if you need further assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are multiple ways to check that. The easiest way is to add a `console.log`, like

```
$("#submitchangepassword").click(function () {
    console.log("submit password clicked!");
    _formValidator.validate();
    refreshTime({ target: this });
});
```

or you could add an alert:

```
$("#submitchangepassword").click(function () {
   alert("submit password clicked!");
    _formValidator.validate();
    refreshTime({ target: this });
});
```

...personally, i prefer the `console.log` method. you can check the console output in firefox or chrome by opening the developer's console.

[edit]
i see i misunderstood the question

you'll need to set a variable to do this. so if the error happens, you set a global variable (lets call it `anErrorOccured`) to true. then you can do

```
$("#submitchangepassword").click(function () {
    _formValidator.validate();
    if(!anErrorOccured){
        refreshTime({ target: this });
    }
});
```

another possible approach is that you implement callbacks:

```
$("#submitchangepassword").click(function () {
    var self = this;
    _formValidator.validate({
        onSuccess:function(){
            refreshTime({ target: self });
        },
        onError:function(){
            alert("an error occured");
        }
    });
});
```

with the `_formValidator` function doing something like this:

```
_formValidator(o){
     //check validity

     if(isValid){
         if(o.onSuccess != undefined){
              o.onSuccess();
         }
     } else {
         if(o.onError != undefined){
              o.onError();
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: thank's for your answer, but i think u don't correctly understand my purpose, base in you'r answer i want do it: $("#submitchangepassword").click(function () { _formValidator.validate(); if(_formValidator.validate(buildError) is Notfired){ refreshTime({ target: this }); } }); Actually,i want use _formValidator.validate() and after this, i check if buildError function (_formValidator.validate()) is fired refreshTime plugin don't fire.

Comment: the option that uses a variable would be ofc not that good, if there are parallel operations running

Answer (score 0):

By my comment I simply meant something like this:

```
var buildErrorFired = false;  // This is declared as a global

 $(document).ready(function () {
     $("#submitchangepassword").click(function () {
         if (!buildErrorFired){
             _formValidator.validate();
             refreshTime({ target: this });
         }
     });
 });

function buildError( config ) {
    buildErrorFired = true;
    var error = $('<div name="formError" id="formError' + config.controlToValidate.replace('#', '') + '" class="form-error-holder"><div class="form-error-icon"></div><div class="form-error"><span class="form-error">' + config.errormessage + '</span></div><div class="clear"></div></div>');
    error.hide();
    error.insertAfter( config.insertAfterControl );
    error.show('fast');
}
```

I do not understand your project well enough to suggest where a `buildErrorFired = false;` reset might go.